# Accessing stuct inside mod in rust

Tags: rust

How can I fix the compile error giving this code example?

```rust
pub mod media {
    pub struct AudioDevice {
        rec_id: i16,
        play_id: i16,
    }

    pub fn audio_device() -> AudioDevice {
        AudioDevice {
            rec_id: -1,
            play_id: -1,
        }
    }
}

struct Card {
    record_id: i16,
    play_id: i16,
}

fn card() -> Card {
    Card {
        record_id: 1,
        play_id: 1,
    }
}

fn main() {
    use media::*;
    let _sample: AudioDevice = crate::media::audio_device();
    let _card = card();
    println!("record_id: {}, play_id: {}", _card.record_id, _card.play_id);
    println!(
        "map rec_id: {}, play_id: {} ",
        _sample.play_id, _sample.rec_id
    );
}
```

```
error[E0616]: field `play_id` of struct `media::AudioDevice` is private
  --> src/main.rs:34:9
   |
34 |         _sample.play_id, _sample.rec_id
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0616]: field `rec_id` of struct `media::AudioDevice` is private
  --> src/main.rs:34:26
   |
34 |         _sample.play_id, _sample.rec_id
   |                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Stack overflow is not very suitable for newbie question, I encourage you to ask this kind of question on other resource a lot of thing are suggest in the [Getting Help](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) section of the rust tag.

Comment: [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e2d1b582df438f65194e54ea7eb95860)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AudioDevice is a public struct, but its member fields are private by default.

```
println!("record_id: {}, play_id: {}", _card.record_id, _card.play_id);
                                             ^
```

You are accessing the private fields from outside the struct.

You can solve this in a couple of ways.  One way is to make the fields public:

```
pub struct AudioDevice {
    pub rec_id: i16,
    pub play_id: i16,
}
```

Comment: it's working, when i read rust programming book this individual member struct can be published not covered. thx a lot Mr.  @Gardener.